# Rails equivilant to django model mixin to keep things DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a rails equivalent to a `ModelMixin` in Django? I'd like all my models to have a uuid field by default. Do I need to add it in every migration file?

Once I have the field in the table, what's the best way to get the uuid field generated? Right now I'm using a concern but I'm wondering wether it'd be better to extend `ActiveRecord::Base` and have all models inherent from that instead of declaring `include Uuid` in each model?

```
module Uuid
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do 
    before_validation :add_uuid, on: :create
  end

  protected

  def add_uuid
    self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to include the field in every model, you'll have to add it to every migration, unless you want to build a custom migration generator.  As for extending ActiveRecord::Base, that's what I would do, since it's going to be in every model.  Have you seen this?  http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-uuid-in-activerecord-with-postgresql/